# Ordering within ARRAY_AGG after GROUP BY in BigQuery

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, sql-order-by

I have a BigQuery table:

```
create or replace table `project.table.mock` as (
  select 1 as col0, 'a' as col1, 'x' as col2
    union all
  select 2 as col0, 'a' as col1, 'y' as col2
    union all
  select 4 as col0, 'b' as col1, 'z' as col2
    union all
  select 8 as col0, 'b' as col1, 'X' as col2
    union all
  select 7 as col0, 'b' as col1, 'Y' as col2
)
```

Visualization:

[image]

I would like to `group by` column `col1`, and `array_agg` the results from `col2`. I would like to have the elements appearing in each array to be sorted by `col0`.

I am now at:

```
select array_agg(col2) as col1arrays from `project.table.mock` group by col1;
```

which gives me:

[image]

The desired output in the second row would be `[z, Y, X]` (as the row where `z` appears in `col2` has 4 in `col0`, the row where `Y` appears in `col2` has 7 in `col0` and the row where `X` appears in `col2` has 8 in `col0`, and 4 < 7 < 8.

**How can I achieve ordering within `array_agg`, as described above, in BigQuery?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `ORDER BY` clause in `ARRAY_AGG()` function.

```sql
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(col2 ORDER BY col1 ASC) AS col1arrays 
  FROM `project.table.mock`  
 GROUP BY col1;
```

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg

```sql
WITH mock as (
  select 1 as col0, 'a' as col1, 'x' as col2
    union all
  select 2 as col0, 'a' as col1, 'y' as col2
    union all
  select 4 as col0, 'b' as col1, 'z' as col2
    union all
  select 8 as col0, 'b' as col1, 'X' as col2
    union all
  select 7 as col0, 'b' as col1, 'Y' as col2
)
select array_agg(col2 ORDER BY col0) as col1arrays from mock group by col1;

output:
+------------+
| col1arrays |
+------------+
| [x,y]      |
| [z,Y,X]    |
+------------+
```